# Javascript Object Literal referring to another property in itself from another property

Tags: javascript, object

I have a object literal:

```
var obj = {
    a : document.getElementById("ex1"),
    b : obj.a.document.getElementsByTagName("div")
};
```

I am having trouble with the b property, for some reason it is not letting that happen. Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Self-references in object literal declarations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literal-declarations)

Answer (score 6):

The modern way to do this is with [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) methods:

```
let obj = {
  firstName: "A’dab",
  lastName: "Farooqi"
  get fullName() {
    return this.firstName+" "+this.lastName;
  },
}
```

So now you can just write `obj.fullName` - no need for the parentheses on the end.

Comment: This should be accepted as the corrected answer, given the most recent updates of the JavaScript. Also, this his a powerful feature that should be more disseminated among developers.

Comment: Seconded - I wish I'd learned about this a long time ago.  This is incredibly useful for establishing complex configurations with generic callables for some properties.

Answer (score 2):

You need two steps:

```
var obj = {
    a : document.getElementById("ex1")
};

obj.b = obj.a.document.getElementsByTagName("div")
```

Or:

```
var temp = document.getElementById("ex1")
var obj = {
    a : temp,
    b : temp.document.getElementsByTagName("div")
};
```

Answer (score 2):

When the property `b` is being defined, `obj` is not defined yet. One way to get around that problem is to make your property a function so that it's not evaluated until called.

```
var obj = {
    a : document.getElementById("ex1"),
    b : function() {
      // This is not evaluated until obj.b() is called
      return obj.a.document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    }
};
obj.b();
```

If you really want it to be a property, you have to do it in two steps as [Tomasz Nurkiewicz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9317725/javascript-object-literal-referring-to-another-property-in-itself-from-another-p/#answer-9317776) shows

Comment: You could use a [getter method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/get) in browsers that support it `var obj={a:document.getElementById("ex1"),get b(){return this.a.document.getElementsByTagName("div")}};`

Comment: @Pumbaa80  By browsers that support it, you mean Firefox only???  A better approach would be to use `Object.defineProperty` since it's available in the latest version of all browsers, but that also requires multiple steps

Comment: Actually, [all browsers but IE<=8 support it](http://robertnyman.com/javascript/javascript-getters-setters.html#regular-getters-and-setters). Browser support for `defineProperty` is the same.